# How did the molecular machinery for recombination originate?

Tags: chromosome, recombination, information-theory, crossover, information

I'm wondering about the origins of genetic recombination. During crossover new chromosomes are created. They have different allele combinations from the original two chromosomes. This process allows the combinatorial explosion needed for biological diversity. I am puzzled by the accuracy of this very complicated process of generating new *genetic information*.

Starting from single cell, When did the first genetic recombination appear? How did it come to existence? In my understanding, it could not have been the result of evolutionary process since genetic recombination must be done right at the first attempt.

Comment: "In my understanding, it could not have been the result of evolutionary process since genetic recombination must be done right at the first attempt" is patently false, but the rest of your question is a good question. As far as I know a definitive answer is unknown but it is an area of active research.

Comment: If only we knew when the fundamental processes in cells arose! What kind of smoking gun did you expect for this one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_crossover#Origins